# Can not find a numeric value

Tags: excel, vba

My code sample is below.

İt is able to find "Hucre" range if the cell value contains "letters and numbers" or "just letters".But when the searched value contains only "numbers" it is not working.Any kind of help will be appreciated.

```
For Each Hucre In Rng1
  If Hucre = a2 Then
  a3 = Hucre.Column
  ActiveWindow.Zoom = True
  Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, a3).End(xlUp).Row
  a4 = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Lastrow, a3)).Rows.Count
  Else: End If
Next Hucre
```

Comment: What is `a2` equal too?

Comment: Was just about to ask the same as @Tom - `a2` is text? `a3` is a long number as is `a4`?  Can I define `Rng1` as `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A5")` to test the code?  If A1 = 123, A2 = abc123, A3 = 123abc, A4 = abcd, A5 = efgh - is that text good enough to test the code with?

Comment: if a2=45736 the program can not find but if a2=c2222 it is able to find.

Comment: also a2 is like this "a2 = ComboBox9.Value"

Comment: You really need to check if it is ever entering your `If` statement. Put a breakpoint on `a3 = Hucre.Column` and run your code. If it pauses it's entering the `If` statement

Comment: Tom, i dont think i need a breakpoint because program is working as i mentioned on my above explanation.thx btw

Comment: Are the values in `Rng1` entered manually?  Or are they the results of formulas?

Comment: rng1 is a result of various calculations

Comment: btw i just made an easier sample which has a range contains 9 different values like below and still if the cell value is numeric it is not working

Comment: Sub Dikdörtgen2_Tıklat()

Dim cell, rng1 As Range

Dim a1 As Variant

Set rng1 = Range(Sheets(1).Cells(5, 3), Sheets(1).Cells(7, 5))

a1 = "3"


For Each cell In rng1

  If cell.Value = a1 Then
  MsgBox "ok"
  Else: End If
  
Next cell

rng1.Activate

End Sub

Comment: uh oh i think this may be about data type

Comment: @MehmetOrcan The breakpoint would have quickly established whether your code was working correctly and indicated if there was a problem on a particular line. It is called debugging. If you don't want to help yourself then I'm not going to stumble around in the dark trying

Comment: In the code you posted in your comment you enter 3 as `"3"` so Excel treats it as a text string, while the value you enter in a cell in C5:E7 would be treated as a number, so `3 doesn't equal "3"`.  So I guess if it wasn't Monday morning when you posted the question and we were a bit more awake we might've spotted that by saying _ searched value contains only "numbers" it is not working_ could mean you had defined your variables incorrectly.  Giving us all the relevant code would have given you an answer two hours ago. :)

Comment: Come on Tom i appreciate your help :) Eventually the data type is the problem.Setting the data type of a2 to string solved everything.But it is funny that that was not a problem on my other pc.Anyways thx for all.